# JavaScript to compare two <div> elements with same ID and style them if their contents are different

Tags: javascript

I need to use JavaScript to dynamically style output from a PHP application that displays product information side by side to compare them (I cannot edit this PHP application).

The fields get the same ID for each product (i.e. if comparing two products, I get two occurrences of s with the same IDs, cf1 through cf5).

I tried using querySelectorAll to get an array of the ID occurrences and then moving through them and comparing them, but got nowhere with it.

HTML:

```
<div class="inner">
  <div class="comparison-div half" id="product-comparison-11">
    <div class="cf field" id="cf-1">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 1 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 1 value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf field" id="cf-2">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 2 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 2 unique value A</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="comparison-div half" id="product-comparison-15">
    <div class="cf field" id="cf-1">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 1 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 1 value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf field" id="cf-2">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 2 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 2 unique value B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var cf1 = document.querySelectorAll("div#cf-1");
var cf2 = document.querySelectorAll("div#cf-2");

for (var i = 0, max = cf1.length; i < max; i++) {
  if (Object.is(cf1[i], cf1[i++]) == false) {
    cf1[i--].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    cf1[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

for (var i = 0, max = cf2.length; i < max; i++) {
  if (Object.is(cf2[i], cf2[i++]) == false) {
    cf2[i--].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    cf2[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coisos/j45p0adt/

I expected cf2 to get a red background as the contents for each of its occurrences are different. Instead, it seems the code has no effect.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead.

Comment: Two elements can't have the same ID

Comment: `Object.is(cf1[i], cf1[i++])`  Two different objects are always going to be different.

Comment: @Andreas & @j08691  You can have elements with the same ID, its maybe not recommend, but if you say did a `document.querySelectorAll('#someid')`, you will get back a list.  And even the global in Chrome, will return a HTMLCollection.

Comment: @Keith you miss the point of an id - it is used to identify something so has to be unique, it is classed as invalid anyway if you validate your code and have duplicate ids so you really shouldn't do it - just because you can doesn't make it right

Comment: @Pete  I totally agree, it's why I said `not recommend`, my reason for saying it, is because it's not the reason why the OP is having problems.  IOW: It won't break your website if you use them.

Comment: @Keith it is invalid code, not just not recommended - you wouldn't do it with any other html so why do it with ids?

Comment: @Keith _"id: ... There **must** not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value ..."_ ([Source](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global))

Comment: Andreas, @j08691: I understand, but the PHP application outputs the duplicate IDs and I cannot change it at this point.

Comment: @Pete  Not sure what part of agree you missed,  my whole point is it's not what's breaking the OP's code.

Comment: @Keith OPs code is broken and should be fixed is my point, although it is not what is causing the main issue being asked about, it's still broken and all I'm saying is you shouldn't be commenting *You can have elements with the same ID,* because you can't, it's invalid

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. IDs MUST be unique for the page. This is not a suggestion, but a statement of fact. You’ll need to change them so that they’re different somehow. I understand that the PHP is generating invalid HTML, and you need to fix that. You can’t solve this problem with JavaScript.

Comment: @Pete  Again, I agree.  Fixing none duplicate ID's is a great super duper idea.  And you can have duplicate ID's,  try it.  Again, before you slam dunk, yes, it's not recommended.  Not sure how else to word things here!  Even big players like youTube use them, again not recommended, but he ho.

Comment: @Keith it’s by definition not valid HTML anymore if you use duplicate IDs. Doesn’t matter who does it. That’s @Pete’s point. It’s more than a recommendation, it’s a rule. Sure, browsers will deal with it instead of grinding to a screeching halt, but that doesn’t mean it’ll work without problems.

Comment: @Nate  `by definition not valid HTML` yes, I agree with that.  And like I keep saying, not recommended.  Not sure were the confusion is here.!!  By the way, it does matter who does it.   YouTube / FaceBook / Redit / BBC news, the list goes on, all have duplicate ID's in there webpages.  `but that doesn’t mean it’ll work without problems`, if problems were caused by this, there are a few big players with some major issues to sort.. :)  It's really ironic, I'm agreeing with lots of what your saying, but `Ids have to be unique` is not true, doesn't matter what the spec says.  Duplicate ID's work.

Comment: If duplicate ids worked, this question wouldn’t exist. ;)

Comment: @Nate  The problem wasn't caused by duplicate ID's.   I'd actually go one further than not having duplicate ID's, and say have no ID's, apart from anchor tags.  Styling use classes, selector's data attributes.  But that's me been really picky :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems..

1. Two different objects will never equal, even.  `Object.is({},{})` is false.
2. cf1[i++], this will increase after your index, ++i would be what your after.

So another idea, is get the innerText, this is a string, and string comparisons will work as expected..

```
if (cf1[i].innerText !== cf1[++i].innerText) {
```

Updated fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/jbv5ywam/

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be at least one incredibly silly mistake in my code.

Comment: It seems that this only catches the first occurrence of a field with different values: if both fields are different, only the first one gets highlighted.

Comment: @Xhiko  If you look in the console you would see the error, problem is your comparing last to previous, but your loop is going too far.  I've updated the fiddle, and also got rid of the `++i`'s etc, as they just confuse things.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in using your ++ operator. comparing cf[i] and cf[i++] will always result to true, the ++ operator increments the value after the current usage if placed after the variable. same with your -- operator.. so if you want the increment to happen in place, you should place it before the variable like this `++i`

Answer (score 0):

for this Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $source = $("#product-comparison-11");
  var $target = $("#product-comparison-15");
  
  $target.find("[data-field]").each(function(i, item){
    var field = $(this).data("field");
    
    if($source.find("[data-field='"+ field +"'] .value").html() !== $(item).find(".value").html()){
      $(item).addClass("red")
    }
    
  })
})
```

```css
.half {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 32px 1%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.label {
  color: #333;
  width: 25%;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fbfbff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-width: 159px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.value {
  color: #333;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.field {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 95%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
  <div class="comparison-div half" id="product-comparison-11">
    <div class="cf field" data-field="cf-1">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 1 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 1 value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf field" data-field="cf-2">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 2 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 2 unique value A</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="comparison-div half" id="product-comparison-15">
    <div class="cf field" data-field="cf-1">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 1 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 1 value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf field" data-field="cf-2">
      <div class="cf-label label">Field 2 label:</div>
      <div class="cf-value value">Field 2 unique value B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd rather avoid jQuery for now.